# GLITCH discord.js update to 12.1.1 error?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, glitch-framework

```
/rbd/pnpm-volume/2811df58-f303-40d7-8428-560fac0ef517/node_modules/.registry.npmjs.org/discord.js/12.1.1/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/Client.js:41
    } catch {
            ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
    at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:139:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:617:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:664:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:566:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:506:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:498:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:597:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/rbd/pnpm-volume/2811df58-f303-40d7-8428-560fac0ef517/node_modules/.registry.npmjs.org/discord.js/12.1.1/node_modules/discord.js/src/index.js:8:11)
```

It said this to me When i upgraded  `my bot's discord.js` to 12.1.1. It's normally running with discord.js 11.4.2 but my bot doesn't run perfectly. Please help me.

Comment: It's called "optional catch binding" and was introduced in Node v10. You'll need to upgrade your Node version.

Comment: Thanks. I will try that.

Comment: Runned. But some discord.js commands didn't run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just upgraded your code from Discord.js 11.4.2 to 12 and above, you should check the [Update Guide](https://discordjs.guide/additional-info/changes-in-v12.html#before-you-start) that way you can make sure you don't have any deprecated/broken code.